How to join on "string contains" in ClickHouse
I need something like
select * from table_a join table_b on table_a.s1 contains table_2.s2
But I did not find information on clickhouse's website.

Try ON table_a.s1 LIKE concat*'%',table_2.s2,'%'), but AFAIK clickhouse supports only equal expression in ON for JOIN
